# Hashmap reverse key lookup

Tags: java

I have a hash map that I reference the key to get the value as such:

```
// define the hashmap
private static final Map<String, String> map;
static {
   map.put("KEY1", "VALUE1");
   map.put("KEY2", "VALUE2");
}

// use the key to get a value 
private static final SomeObject MyObject1 = MyObject.compile(map.get("KEY1"));

...
```

but later in my code I get a value back and I need to get the key (how can I do something like this):

```
// some method that returns a value from the map based on conditional matching
String theValue = <SomeMethodThatReturns "VALUE1" or "VALUE2">();

// now I have theValue now **how can I get the key?**
System.out.println("Found Key Match: " + map.getKeyFromValue(theValue);  // ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a [Guava BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) instead of a HashMap:

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint enables bimaps to support an "inverse view", which is another bimap containing the same entries as this bimap but with reversed keys and values.

Then, you can do:

```
String key = map.inverse.get(theValue);
```

Comment: Yes, the Guava byline is: "Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 1.6+"

Comment: Worked as advertised!  Also, the two answers made most sense to me (even though they were from the same author).  =)

Answer (score 1):

If using a Guava BiMap is not an option ([see my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20278675/1212960)), then you're stuck with iterating over the map entries until you find the one with your matching value:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entries : map.entrySet())
{
  if (entry.getValue().equals(theValue())
  {
    return entry.getKey();               // we found it
  }
}

// We couldn't find it ...
```

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder: they're two _different_ answers. If you can point me to a meta-post explaining that this is a bad thing to do, I'll change it, but it seems _the right thing_ to do to me.